# Passing a string to $

Tags: jquery

Trying to get a grip on **CoffeeScript** and **jQuery** by doing the Code School CoffeeScript course.

One of the excerpts used is `$("<li>" + name + "</li>")`. I managed to figure out that `$` is an alias for `jQuery` (right?), so I guess this means we're calling the jQuery function with a string (`name` is a string, surrounded by two literals).

So... what does the `jQuery` function do on its own? Tried looking at api.jquery.com, having trouble figuring it out. Thank you!

Comment: *"surrounded by two literals"* It's actually three strings being concatenated into a single string. You are passing a string that represents html into jQuery, jQuery converts that into an html fragment, similar to doing `var li = document.createElement("li").innerHTML = name;` though jQuery may use innerHTML directly on the whole string depending on how complex the string is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this instance you are using jQuery to create a DOM element.

An `<li>` with some (text I'm assuming) that is in the variable `name`

> If a **string** is passed as the parameter to **$()**, jQuery examines the
>   string to see if it looks like HTML (i.e., it has  somewhere
>   within the string). If not, the string is interpreted as a selector
>   expression, as explained above. But if the string appears to be an
>   HTML snippet, jQuery attempts to create new DOM elements as described
>   by the HTML. Then a jQuery object is created and returned that refers
>   to these elements.

The structure for creating DOM elements with jQuery is:

```
$( html, props )
```

Check out these **[jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements)** to read more about the jQuery selector.

> **html**:  A string defining a single, standalone, HTML element (e.g. 
>   or ).
>
> **props**:  A map of attributes, events, and methods to call on the
>   newly-created element.

As we can see in your example we only pass *html*. `$("<li>" + name + "</li>")`

Answer (score 1):

You are actully passing a string to the jQuery `"<li>" + name + "</li>"` this is actually a concatenate the `3 string` to form `1 string`. Which is passed to the jQuery function which it parsed and chaeck

**if its a string** : it is parsed to form a  dome selector with complex manuplation to selec element on the basis of id,class,and more complex selector

**if its a object** : dom related to the object is selected.

**if its this (javascript Object)** :  it is converted to jQuery object